# breaking a while loop after one iteration

Tags: c#, excel

I am a beginner programmer and I am trying to develop my programming skills. My end goal is to build a data management system for medical billing companies.

I'm at the very beginning stages of learning programming languages and my first little mini-task is to create a basic Windows Application with C# that opens up an excel file, checks for the last line that has data on it, goes one line down from it and adds the data that is in the text boxes. After adding one line of data, I want it to stop and save the file (as in only add one line of data)

So far, I've been able to do everything perfectly.. except one thing. I used a while loop to check if the first cell is null or not:

```
while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] !=null)
```

With `inc++;` and `oSheet.Cells[inc,X] = "text";` lines, I've gotten my program to automatically drop down to the next line and add the data but it doesn't stop! It keeps going infinitely! My best thinking told me to include an if statement stating that if the incremented cell is not empty, than to break the while loop. For a reason I can't understand, when I include that if break statement, the code never executes at all. I thought that if the if statement was below the inc++; and cell filling statements, the while loop would check the first cell, if it was not null it would drop to the next cell, if the cell was null then it would add text and then run through the if statement seeing that the cell it just added text to is in fact not null and it would break the while loop. That doesn't seem to happen. When I include the if break statement, nothing happens. Here are both versions of the code:

Without if break statement:

```
    private void btnCreateClaim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = oXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\CSAIO4D\testsheet1.xlsx");
        oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;




        int inc = 1;
        while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null)
        {
            inc++;

                oSheet.Cells[inc, 1] = txtClientName.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 2] = txtState.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 3] = txtAlphaPrefix.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 4] = txtInsurance.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 5] = txtStartDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 6] = txtEndDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 7] = txtUnits.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 8] = txtLOC.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 9] = txtRate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 10] = txtAmount.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 11] = txtAuth.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 12] = txtBilledDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 13] = txtPrimaryDiagnosis.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 14] = txtBillType.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 15] = txtRevenueCode.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 16] = txtHCPCS.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 17] = txtCPT_Code.Text.ToString();

        }

        oWB.Save();
    }
```

With if break statement:

```
    private void btnCreateClaim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = oXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\CSAIO4D\testsheet1.xlsx");
        oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;




        int inc = 1;
        while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null)
        {
            inc++;

                oSheet.Cells[inc, 1] = txtClientName.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 2] = txtState.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 3] = txtAlphaPrefix.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 4] = txtInsurance.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 5] = txtStartDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 6] = txtEndDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 7] = txtUnits.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 8] = txtLOC.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 9] = txtRate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 10] = txtAmount.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 11] = txtAuth.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 12] = txtBilledDate.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 13] = txtPrimaryDiagnosis.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 14] = txtBillType.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 15] = txtRevenueCode.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 16] = txtHCPCS.Text.ToString();
                oSheet.Cells[inc, 17] = txtCPT_Code.Text.ToString();

            if(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null)
            {
                break;
            }

        }

        oWB.Save();
    }
```

Can someone explain to me what I need to add/do different to get it to keep going down until it finds the first empty cell in column one and once it does, post the information in the text boxes and then stop after posting it once?

Comment: The while loop in your code is actually modifying data starting from the row one. What you need is to reach to the last row and then add data in the next row. So while loop should only increase `inc` value and after that data should be added. So you need to change while loop to `while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null){ inc++;}` after this you should write `oSheet.Cells[inc, 1].... So on`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! What you are saying is making sense so I tried it. For some reason it's not adding any data to the cells though :(.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Are you getting any error while calling Save method on `oWB`?

Comment: Didn't debug the code. The people below answered it for us. It was my incorrect use of null. Well your answer addressed my first problem. I had two problems. First problem was incorrectly using null instead of string.empty and second problem was including the text filling code in the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is true:

```
while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that means the loop should continue. But by adding this:

```
        if(oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null)
        {
            break;
        }
```

you're telling it to exit the loop if that same condition is true. So it's going to exit after checking the very first row, just as you've seen.

Also, is that check - `oSheet.Cells[inc,1] != null` the correct way to determine if a cell is empty? I don't think it is. I think `oSheet.Cells[inc, 1]` is always going to return a `Range` object. The cell may or may not be empty, but that's never going to be null.

Try this:

```
while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1].Text != string.Empty)
```

You can also use

```
oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

to get the number of rows that aren't empty. Like this - no loop required.

```
var emptyRow = oSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1;
oSheet.Cells[emptyRow, 1] = txtClientName.Text.ToString();
oSheet.Cells[emptyRow, 2] = txtState.Text.ToString();
```

Comment: using while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1].Text != string.Empty) worked! It's only adding one new line of data every time I run the code! It saves it and next time I run it, the same thing happens. Thank you! Question answered.  This is the first question I've ever posted on here. Is there a way I can mark my question answered?

Comment: It's somewhere on the screen to mark an answer as correct or answered. I just can't see it because it's not my question. But it's on there somewhere.

Comment: So this wasn't working because I was incorrectly asking for the contents of the cell with the use of 'null'. Is there a reason why Visual Studio didn't flag this as a syntax error? Just trying to learn more. No worries either way.

Comment: The problem is in the Excel object model. It's oddly and inconsistently designed. `Cells[x, y]` returns a `Range`, but you can set it using a `string`. Some properties return `object` and you have to cast it to some other type. It does other evil stuff. Check your task manager. You might have 20 instances of Excel running that you didn't know about. If you plan on doing lots of work in Excel I'd recommend looking at [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). Excel Interop will make you hate being a programmer and maybe even life itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to move the code setting your values outside the loop? e.g.

```
private void btnCreateClaim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application oXL;
    Excel._Workbook oWB;
    Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

    oXL = new Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = true;

    oWB = oXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\CSAIO4D\testsheet1.xlsx");
    oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;

    int inc = 1;
    while(oSheet.Cells[inc,1].Text != String.Empty)
    {
        inc++;
    }

    oSheet.Cells[inc, 1] = txtClientName.Text.ToString();
    oSheet.Cells[inc, 2] = txtState.Text.ToString();
    // etc...

    oWB.Save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! What you are saying is making sense so I tried it. For some reason it's not adding any data to the cells though :(.

Comment: Just edited to check whether the cell has any text, rather than checking for null, as Scott Hannen suggests.

Comment: After looking at this again, this was the answer I needed as shown below. I didn't realize you had changed the while loop changing how to look at the cell (using string.empty instead of null). Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Programs are always easier to manage when the logic is broken into manageable pieces. In this case, I suggest you write a separate function just to find the next blank row. It might look something like this:

```
    private int FindFirstBlankRow(Excel._Worksheet oSheet)
    {
        int y = 1;
        while (oSheet.Cells[y, 1] != null) y++;
        return y;
    }
```

Then in your main function it should be simple:

```
    private void btnCreateClaim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;

        oXL = new Excel.Application();
        oXL.Visible = true;

        oWB = oXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\CSAIO4D\testsheet1.xlsx");
        oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;

        int inc = FindFirstBlankRow(oSheet);

        oSheet.Cells[inc, 1] = txtClientName.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 2] = txtState.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 3] = txtAlphaPrefix.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 4] = txtInsurance.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 5] = txtStartDate.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 6] = txtEndDate.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 7] = txtUnits.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 8] = txtLOC.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 9] = txtRate.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 10] = txtAmount.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 11] = txtAuth.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 12] = txtBilledDate.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 13] = txtPrimaryDiagnosis.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 14] = txtBillType.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 15] = txtRevenueCode.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 16] = txtHCPCS.Text.ToString();
        oSheet.Cells[inc, 17] = txtCPT_Code.Text.ToString();

        oWB.Save();
    }
```